# Get AD members list from different OUs in single script

Tags: active-directory

I need Powershell script for the following.
There are multiple OUs in the domain.
I would like to extract users along with the OU which the user belongs to by it's side in a output .csv file

Comment: Can you try using Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName | Export-csv -path "C:\Sample\UserwithOU.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The results in Distinguished name shows CN =XYZ,OU=ABC, DC=123,DC=com. Is there any possibility to get only ou name?

Comment: Hello @Chandratarak, can you try this `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object Name, @{n='OUName'; e={$_.DistinguishedName -replace '.+?,OU=(.+?),(?:OU|DC)=.+','$1'}} | Export-csv -path "C:\Sample\UserwithOU.csv" -NoTypeInformation`